# How to validate RadioButton options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello everyone I'm creating a `mcq` type form where user can choose any answer and submit after submission it'll tell u that whether you've selected the correct answers or not. if you selected the correct answer then it'll prompt you okay the answer is correct and if you given the wrong answer it'll prompt u that this is the wrong answer along with the actual answer. I've already done this but my problem is when i'm choosing the correct value its prompting that correct answer after that if i choose the wrong option it'll give me that the answer is wrong but the previous "correct answer" line is not removing after the new prompt. How can i do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sid").click(function() {

    if (!$("input[@name=q1]:checked").val()) {
      alert("You're not done yet!");
    } else {
      var cat1name = "1";
      var cat2name = "None";



      var cat1 = ($("input[@name=q1]:checked").val() != "a");
      var cat2 = (!cat1);
      var categories = [];

      if (cat1) {
        categories.push(cat1name)
      };


      if (cat2) {
        categories.push(cat2name)
      };


      var catStr = 'You answered the following questions incorrectly: ' + categories.join(', ') + '';
      $("#categorylist").text(catStr);
      $("#categorylist").show("slow");

      if (cat1) {
        $("#category1").show("slow");
      };

      if (cat2) {
        $("#category2").show("slow");
      };

      {
        $("#closing").show("slow");
      };
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#results1").click(function() {

    if (!$("input[@name=q2]:checked").val()) {
      alert("You're not done yet!");
    } else {
      var cat3name = "2";
      var cat4name = "None";



      var cat3 = ($("input[@name=q2]:checked").val() != "b");
      var cat4 = (!cat3);
      var categories = [];

      if (cat3) {
        categories.push(cat3name)
      };


      if (cat4) {
        categories.push(cat4name)
      };

      var catStr = 'You answered the following questions incorrectly: ' + categories.join(', ') + '';
      $("#categorylist").text(catStr);
      $("#categorylist").show("slow");

      if (cat3) {
        $("#category3").show("slow");
      };

      if (cat4) {
        $("#category4").show("slow");
      };

      {
        $("#closing").show("slow");
      };
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.answers li {
  list-style: upper-alpha;
}

label {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#results {
  background: #dddada;
  color: 000000;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#results:hover {
  background: #3d91b8;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#results1 {
  background: #dddada;
  color: 000000;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#results1:hover {
  background: #3d91b8;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#categorylist {
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: none;
}

#category1,
#category2,
#category3,
#category4,
#category5,
#category6,
#category7,
#category8,
#category9,
#category10,
#category11 {
  display: none;
}

#closing {
  display: none;
  font-style: italic;
}

#sid {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="testmcq.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="linkmcq.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p class="question">1. What is the answer to this question?</p>
  <ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">Answer 1</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">Answer 2</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">Answer 3</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">Answer 4</label><br/>
  </ul>


  <!--<div id="results">Show me the answers!</div>-->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="sid">Link Button</button>

  <div id="category1">
    <p><strong>Question 1:</strong> The correct answer is the <strong>Answer 1</strong>.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="category2">
    <p>Correct Answer!</p>
  </div>
  &nbsp
  <p class="question">2. What is the answer to this question?</p>
  <ul class="answers">
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a"><label for="q2a">Answer 1</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b"><label for="q2b">Answer 2</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c"><label for="q2c">Answer 3</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d"><label for="q2d">Answer 4</label><br/>
  </ul>



  <div id="results1">
    Show me the answers!
  </div>

  <div id="category3">
    <p><strong>Question 2:</strong> The correct answer is the <strong>Answer 2</strong>.</p>
  </div>

  <!--<div id="category2">
<p><strong>Question 2:</strong> The correct answer is the <strong>Answer 2</strong>.</p>
</div>-->

  <div id="category4">
    <p>Correct Answer!</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found many errors in your code.

If you need to check the radiobutton values you might use:

```
$("input:radio[name='q1']:checked").val();
```

I've made a possible solution using jQuery 1.11.0, so you could start with this.

> **Updated:**

By default you need to hide the messages when you clic in the button.

```
$("#category1, #category2").hide();
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sid").on("click", function() {
    $("#category1, #category2").hide();
    var q1 = $("input:radio[name='q1']:checked");
    if (q1.val() === undefined) {
      alert("You're not done yet!");
    } else {
      var cat1name = "1";
      var cat2name = "None";

      var cat1 = (q1.val() != "a");
      var cat2 = (!cat1);
      var categories = [];

      if (cat1) {
        categories.push(cat1name)
      }

      if (cat2) {
        categories.push(cat2name)
      }
      console.log(categories);


      var catStr = 'You answered the following questions incorrectly: ' + categories.join(', ') + '';
      $("#categorylist").text(catStr);
      $("#categorylist").show("slow");

      if (cat1) {
        $("#category1").show("slow");
      }

      if (cat2) {
        $("#category2").show("slow");
      }

      $("#closing").show("slow");
    }
  });

  $("#results1").on("click", function() {
    $("#category3, #category4").hide();
    var q2 = $("input:radio[name='q2']:checked");
    if (q2.val() === undefined) {
      alert("You're not done yet!");
    } else {
      var cat3name = "2";
      var cat4name = "None";

      var cat3 = (q2.val() != "b");
      var cat4 = (!cat3);
      var categories = [];

      if (cat3) {
        categories.push(cat3name)
      };

      if (cat4) {
        categories.push(cat4name)
      };

      var catStr = 'You answered the following questions incorrectly: ' + categories.join(', ') + '';
      $("#categorylist").text(catStr);
      $("#categorylist").show("slow");

      if (cat3) {
        $("#category3").show("slow");
      }

      if (cat4) {
        $("#category4").show("slow");
      }
      $("#closing").show("slow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.answers li {
  list-style: upper-alpha;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
#results {
  background: #dddada;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
#results:hover {
  background: #3d91b8;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
#results1 {
  background: #dddada;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
#results1:hover {
  background: #3d91b8;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
#categorylist {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
#category1,
#category2,
#category3,
#category4,
#category5,
#category6,
#category7,
#category8,
#category9,
#category10,
#category11 {
  display: none;
}
#closing {
  display: none;
  font-style: italic;
}
#sid {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="question">1. What is the answer to this question?</p>
<ul class="answers">
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a">
  <label for="q1a">Answer 1</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b">
  <label for="q1b">Answer 2</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c">
  <label for="q1c">Answer 3</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d">
  <label for="q1d">Answer 4</label>
  <br/>
</ul>
<!--<div id="results">Show me the answers!</div>-->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="sid">Link Button</button>
<div id="category1">
  <p><strong>Question 1:</strong> The correct answer is the <strong>Answer 1</strong>.</p>
</div>
<div id="category2">
  <p>Correct Answer!</p>
</div>&nbsp
<p class="question">2. What is the answer to this question?</p>
<ul class="answers">
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a">
  <label for="q2a">Answer 1</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b">
  <label for="q2b">Answer 2</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c">
  <label for="q2c">Answer 3</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d">
  <label for="q2d">Answer 4</label>
  <br/>
</ul>
<div id="results1">Show me the answers!</div>
<div id="category3">
  <p><strong>Question 2:</strong> The correct answer is the <strong>Answer 2</strong>.</p>
</div>
<!--<div id="category2">
<p><strong>Question 2:</strong> The correct answer is the <strong>Answer 2</strong>.</p>
</div>-->
<div id="category4">
  <p>Correct Answer!</p>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/wun37at7/1/)

Comment: thank u for ur valuable answer i'll keep that in my mind... but the problem still remains :(

Comment: when i'm choosing the correct value its prompting "correct answer" by printing the line but immediately after that if i choose the wrong option it'll give me that the answer is wrong but the previous "correct answer" line is not removing after the new prompt i.e under the previous "correct answer" line it's simply printing  "wrong answer" but i need to remove that "correct answer" line..pls help !!!

Comment: Nice. Don't forget to accept my answer like a final solution. Thanks.

Comment: can u pls tell me after showing the correct or wrong answer how do i hide that line by clicking the button ????

Comment: btw i'm using slideToggle() instead of show() its working but if i continuosly press the button 4-5 times repeatedly then its working one time..pls help !!!

Comment: @SiddharthaDasgupta Can you show me what you have achieved in a jsFiddle link? http://jsfiddle.net/